# How can i fix Facebook PHP sdk Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i just created facebook app, and got App ID & App Secret.
then i downloaded facebook PHP sdk from github.
i made changes to example.php by adding my app id & secret
then i ftp all "facebook-php-sdk-master" to server. and run the example.php
but out put was below error..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 7: couldn't connect to host thrown in /home/u917057965/public_html/app/src/base_facebook.php on line 989
```

i was following a tut on youtube. why i get this error ?
and what should i do ?

please help me.
Thanks

Comment: _"couldn't connect to host"_ - the system you're testing on most likely blocks outgoing connections. If it's your local machine you're developing on, then check your firewall settings etc.; if it's a "real" web server, then contact the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your hosting provider does not allow outgoing connections.
so, i think there is no wrong with yours.
contact your hosting administrator to fix it.

Comment: thanks. i am using free webhosting servise. so, do you think is that is the problem?